# Catch reject inner join ssis

Tags: ssis, inner-join, talend

I'm using SSIS. How Can I catch a reject of inner join with MERGE JOIN in SSIS like a lookup inner join reject with tMap in Talend Open Studio?

Comment: If you would take the effort describe the required Talend functionality we might be able to answer.

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved in SSIS without a temporary table.

I would create a Data Flow Task.  Within that I would add an Excel Source for the equivalent of Table2 in the SQL solution propose above.  Then I would add a Cache Transform to store that data in a new Cache.

Then I would add a 2nd Data Flow Task.  Within I would add an Excel Source for the equivalent of Table1.  Then I would add a Lookup transform and point it at the Cache created previously. I would configure this to Redirect non-matching rows to no match output, and on the Columns page match on Id.

Then I would add a Destination object to deliver the output wherever you want.  This would be connected to the No Match Output from the Lookup.

Comment: It seems helpful. I'll try it. Thank you.

Comment: @Alaedjens If you found the answer helpful you should accept it so that other users coming across this problem know what to do in future. Otherwise it might be best to edit your OP or post a comment under the answers that don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used SSIS but you should be able to get what you want with the following SQL query:

```
SELECT t1.Id
FROM Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
WHERE t2.Id IS NULL
```

This will do a left outer join between the two tables, selecting everything in the left table (the first one named, so Table1 here) and where it can will match with Table2 but also leave any non matched left table entries. The `WHERE` will then only select the rows where it has been unable to make a match leaving you with just the `INNER JOIN` rejects.

Comment: It does not help me so much because I'm using an Excel Source component as a source of data and not a database. Anyway I will try to use your SQL query to solve the probleme. Thank you.

Comment: Apologies, I've never used SSIS so don't know if this functionality exists in a graphical way. An option for you here could be to load the Excel data into a temporary table before running the join and then dropping the table.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm going to proceed. Thanks a lot Sir.